# Postgres transaction id wraparound for non-user tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I was at risk of hitting transaction id wraparound on a large Postgres 10 cluster due to a long-running transaction that was not idle (although it actually was in some sense, because it was stuck in the active state due to an issue with the Cassandra FDW that was being used in the query). I caught it in time and with prodigious use of `vacuum freeze` was able to get everything back under control...maybe.

Everything looks fine at the database level:

```
warehouse=# SELECT datname, age(datfrozenxid) FROM pg_database;
  datname  |   age
-----------+----------
 postgres  | 85253797
 template1 | 85253797
 template0 | 85253797
 warehouse | 89423564
 repmgr    | 85253797
(5 rows)
```

but I'm still seeing these in the logs and having trouble with replication (currently disabled until things get fixed):

```
WARNING:  oldest xmin is far in the past
HINT:  Close open transactions soon to avoid wraparound problems.
```

Looking in the various databases using this query I see something concerning: `xid` ages right up at the wraparound limit, but all for things that can't be `vacuum freeze`'d like indexes, sequences, and system tables:

```
select relname, age from (select relname, age(relfrozenxid) age from pg_class) a order by age desc;
                  relname                  |    age
-------------------------------------------+------------
 user_mappings                             | 2147483647
 pg_stat_sys_indexes                       | 2147483647
 pg_stat_user_indexes                      | 2147483647
 pg_statio_all_indexes                     | 2147483647
 pg_statio_sys_indexes                     | 2147483647
 ...
```

There was a restart as part of recovery from this because it was the only way to get the stuck query to clear, so I don't think I still have anything that could be causing high xids like long-lived prepared statements, temp tables, etc., so it's not clear to me what's causing the issue.

So, a couple related questions about all this:

1. Is this a problem (beyond generating a bunch of annoying error messages)?
2. Can I do anything about it?
3. Could this interfere with replication, where I'm now unable to get the replica to be caught up (always shows me a steady stream of error messages on primary and replica about missing WALs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables you show are all views, and the age of 2147483647 just reflects that `relfrozenxid` is 0 for them.

Views have no tuples, and they need no `VACUUM`, so these are false positives.

Can you determine what exactly causes the warning?

There are things that block `VACUUM` and survive a restart: replication slots and prepared transactions.

Your replication probably just fell behind, I don't think there is a direct connection to the transaction ID issue (but I can't be certain because you showed no log).

Comment: `select count(1) from  pg_prepared_xacts;` returns 0, so not related to prepared statements I think. similarly `select count(1) from pg_replication_slots;` returns 0. as i say, i'm also seeing this for all sequences, indexes, and other non-table items in `pg_class` for other databases (just showed what was happening in the `postgres` database as an example since it's the same for everyone).

Comment: That's perfectly normal. The value is 0 for anything other than tables.